# Identifying an app by the ios provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Please see the below XML excerpt for a provisioning profile for an, as of now, unidentifiable app I found rooted in my iPhone running ios 13.3.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppIDName</key>
    <string>zhihuiguotsing</string>
    <key>ApplicationIdentifierPrefix</key>
    <array>
    <string>Y9UTWBRKS8</string>
    </array>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2020-03-19T09:54:48Z</date>
    <key>Platform</key>
    <array>
        <string>iOS</string>
    </array>
    <key>IsXcodeManaged</key>
    <false/>
    <key>DeveloperCertificates</key>
    <array>
        <data>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</data>
    </array>

                                                                        
    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
                
                <key>inter-app-audio</key>
        <true/>
                
                <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>Y9UTWBRKS8.com.guoqing.guotsing</string>
                
                <key>com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension</key>
        <array>
                <string>app-proxy-provider</string>
                <string>content-filter-provider</string>
                <string>packet-tunnel-provider</string>
                <string>dns-proxy</string>
        </array>
                
                <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
                <string>Y9UTWBRKS8.*</string>
        </array>
                
                <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
                
                <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
                
                <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>Y9UTWBRKS8</string>
                
                <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
        <string>*</string>
                
                <key>com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api</key>
        <array>
                <string>allow-vpn</string>
        </array>

    </dict>
    <key>ExpirationDate</key>
    <date>2021-03-19T09:54:48Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>zs</string>
    <key>ProvisionsAllDevices</key>
    <true/>
    <key>TeamIdentifier</key>
    <array>
        <string>Y9UTWBRKS8</string>
    </array>
    <key>TeamName</key>
    <string>Qingjian Group Co., Ltd</string>
    <key>TimeToLive</key>
    <integer>365</integer>
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>f18d90b6-3f4c-40a7-b482-4434b9ba355e</string>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have googled whatever potentially identifying information, including AppIDName, application-identifier, TeamIdentifier, etc., with no results. Any ideas on how I can identify the app?

Comment: Looks like it might be an enterprise signed app.

Comment: Does the inter-app-audio entitlement allow audio recording?

Comment: not specifically - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/inter-app-audio

Comment: I have suspicions that this software is being used to monitor me.  Any ideas as to how I could remove it?

Comment: Check in settings general profiles for any enterprise app certificate trusts or put your phone in DFU mode and set it up as a new phone and don’t recover anything from backup